# HTML Generation from Adobe AIR with Actionscript (AS3)

Tags: html, actionscript-3, air

Which is the fastest way to generate HTML from a MXML GUI? I would like to print a complex GUI

Comment: What kind of HTML do you want to generate? What for? We need more details about what you try to achieve.

Comment: Well, I had tried to print a complex GUI with alivePDF and the results are not valid for us. My next idea is to generate/export the different screens we have in the AIR application (MXML and AS3) to HTML, save this HTML content to a local file and then open a web browser to display the same content. That way, all the forms can be printed with the web browser. Alternative ideas would also be very welcome. I have a complex document with textfields, comboboxes, etc and alivePDF prints only what you see on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to print an MXML form, why don't you use the [print API directly available in AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#includeExamplesSummary)?

Comment: Well, this might work if our forms were one page or less. I have a big document to generate, spanning several pages with different sections. The printAPI is in this case useless, I had tested it. We have scrollers.

Comment: Even with scroller, the advantage of this API is that you can create your own printable view with any controls you want. Just attach them to your printable container with the height to want to avoid scrollers. You can even do it on several pages.

Comment: I tried the solution you mentioned and I get the same results: I cannot generate bigger screenshots that one page. I have thought about XML + XSLT for the HTML generation, but it will take some time to build this solution.